# Can you dynamically display the value of the slider in Animate?

Tags: graphics, animation

It would be nice to be able to see the value of t changing as the animation progresses even if it is updating so fast that you have to stop the slider to read the number.

```
Animate[Graphics[{Circle[], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}], {t, 0, 6}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: While displaying it in the graphic is probably nicer, just wanted to mention another workaround: use `Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}], {t, 0, 6}]` and click the little plus next to the slider. This will show a panel of buttons and the value, and one of those buttons will let you play the animation.

Comment: Yes, Manipulate does the trick!

Comment: Or `Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}], {t, 0, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]` or `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}], {t, 0, 6, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", AnimationRunning -> False, 
  ControlType -> Animator}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** You can simply add the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` in `Animator` control:

```
Animate[Graphics[{Circle[], PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}],
  {t, 0, 6, Appearance -> "Labeled", AnimationRunning -> False}]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, you can define a custom control with desired elements combining a labeled slider with animator elements:

```
ClearAll[labeledAnimator]
labeledAnimator = Row[{Slider[##, Appearance -> "Labeled"], 
     Animator[##, AnimationRunning -> False, 
      AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
        "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}]}, 
    Spacer[1]] &;
```

Use `labeledAnimator` with `Manipulate` (it does not work with `Animator`) and add the option  `AppearanceElements -> {}` to get the `Animator` look/feel:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[], PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}], 
   {t, 0, 6, labeledAnimator, AnimationRunning -> False}, 
 AppearanceElements -> {}]
```

[image]

**3.** Using a variation on Alexey Popkov's idea: use a `LabeledSlider` as control label and remove the progress slider default list of animator appearance elements:

```
Animate[Graphics[{Circle[], PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}],
 {{t, 0, Dynamic@LabeledSlider[t, {0, 10}]}, 0, 10, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", 
    "DirectionButton", "ResetButton"}}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent solution described by @kglr, one can make a custom label. Try this:

```
Animate[Graphics[{Circle[], PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}],
 {{t, 0, Dynamic@
    Panel[Row[{Style["Time: ", Blue, 14], Style[t, Red, 14]}], 
     ImageSize -> {180, 50}]}, 0, 10}]
```

with the effect of

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not aware, you can simply include t in the layout of
the content area :

```
Animate[Column[{
   t,
   Graphics[{Circle[], Point[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}]}]
   }]
 , {t, 0, 6}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[[image]][